# How to use GraalVM in Java? class not found exception

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

I want to make this example to work: https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java

But I get an exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/vm/ci/services/Services

I included GraalVM via Maven

The same exception is thrown in this minimal example

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = Context.create("js");
        context.eval("js", "console.log('Hello from Earth')");
    }
}
```

The pom

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.sdk/graal-sdk -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
<version>19.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
<artifactId>js</artifactId>
<version>19.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js-scriptengine -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
<artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
<version>19.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.compiler/compiler -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.graalvm.compiler</groupId>
<artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
<version>19.1.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using jdk-12.0.1 (Open JDK) and working on a Windows 10 computer.

Somewhere on the internet I found that this

```
 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler
```

should be included as VM arguments. When I do that the exception changes to:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.runtime.hotspot.AbstractHotSpotTruffleRuntimeAccess (in unnamed module @0x2d8e6db6) cannot access class jdk.vm.ci.services.Services (in module jdk.internal.vm.ci) because module jdk.internal.vm.ci does not export jdk.vm.ci.services to unnamed module @0x2d8e6db6

Maybe there is a problem with the modules: modules-info.java

```
module App {
exports testinggraal;

requires org.graalvm.sdk;
requires java.scripting;
requires org.graalvm.truffle;
requires org.graalvm.js;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo and I looked into this, seems the problem is that the profiles are set up to work **only** with JDK11.

If you apply the following patch to the pom file of graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo it should work with JDK12 as well (as show by https://travis-ci.org/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo/jobs/564052535)

```
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index e2a76c1..95cfa2c 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
     <profile>
         <id>jdk11</id>
         <activation>
-                <jdk>11</jdk>
+                <jdk>[11,</jdk>
         </activation>
         <dependencies>
             <dependency>
```

Comment: Confirmed it as working. So I wonder why you need to have the profile for `jdk8` in the pom. If I remove it maven can not resolve the `Context` class anymore, even so it should only use the profile for `jdk12`. Also the `source` & `target` level in the maven-compiler-plugin should be changed to 12.

Comment: The jdk8 profile is for when it is used with GraalVM which is currently based off a JDK 8.

Comment: I still get the same error. I wonder about the difference between including graalvm using Maven vs pointing JAVA_HOME to a graalvm. I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Just checked, and running `mvn package` works for me on windows 10 as well, using `openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16` and applying the patch above.

Comment: Thank you BoriS. Maybe there is something wrong with the modules-info.java I use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do to be honest. Can you run the demo (as it is in https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo or not?